# Ajax get request for a json file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to jQuery and Ajax and im trying to use jQuery and ajax to make a request for a JSON FILE.
This is the stucture.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  }
]
```

I want to put this into an array of objects.
My code is this

```
 $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", function(data, status){
        array=JSON.parse(data);
           join();
           render();

    });
});
```

That doesnt work but this does

```
 var xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  //console.log(this.readyState+" "+this.status);
  if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)
  {
     array=JSON.parse(this.response);

        join();
        render();


  }
 }
 xhttp.open("GET","https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",true);
 xhttp.send();
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: No need of `JSON.parse` i guess! just do `array = data`

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work` ? What's the code for `join` and `render` ?

Comment: Nothing happens. 
That code is ok (join and render), because everything works when i use AJAX without the jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()` like below:-

```
$.getJSON( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", function( data ) {

  console.log(data);//check data coming properly or not 

  //do rest of the coding accordingly
});
```

Comment: JQuery version minimun ?

Answer (score 0):

This would populate the myObjects array, with the objects coming in the JSON.

```
let myObjects = [];    
$("button").click(function(){
        $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", function(data, status){
        array=JSON.parse(data);
        if(response)
        {
        data.forEach(function (obj) {
           myObjects.push(obj)
        })

           join();
           render();
        }
        else {
           response=true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there's no need to check `response` for 2 reasons:

1. There's no argument with this name passed by `$.get`.
2. The function,  in which the code is, is a `success` callback. So you are sure to have a succesful response and your data is present.

So you could write your code like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", function(data, status){
        array=JSON.parse(data);
        join();
        render();
    });
});
```

If the data is already in `JSON`, you don't need to call `JSON.parse`:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", function(data, status){
        join();
        render();
    });
});
```